# Why Do I Keep Getting This Error for my circle code?

Tags: c#

Can't figure out why i keep getting this error.

Error    1: does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point

It ran on one coding website, but not when i put it into visual studio 2012.

```
 using System;
public class Circle
{
    private int diameter;
    private double pi;
    private double radius;
    private double area;

    public int getDiameter()
    {
        return diameter;
    }
    public void setDiameter(int diameter)
    {
        diameter = 0;
    }
    public double getPi(double pi)
    {
        return pi;
    }
    public void setPi(double pi)
    {
        pi = 3.142;
    }
    public Circle(double rad)
    {
        radius = rad;
    }
    public Circle()
    {
        radius = diameter / 2;
    }
    public void setRadius(double rad)
    {
        radius = diameter / 2;
    }
    public double getRadius()
    {
        return radius;
    }
    public double getArea()
    {
        return area = pi * radius * radius;
    }

}
public class TestClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Circle myCircle = new Circle();
        Console.WriteLine("The circle's area is: " + myCircle.getArea());
        Console.WriteLine("The circle's radius is: " + myCircle.getRadius());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The runtime looks for a method called `Main`. Just that. `main` does not count. Remember, C# is case sensitive.

So change your entry-pont method's name to "Main".

As a note, common style dictates that *all* methods in C# should start with a capital letter, so you may want to consider changing your style there in the rest of your code.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment? While this *is* a "typo" its one thats easy to make, and not necessarily easy to spot if you don't know this rule.

Comment: to clarify - methods in c# can have any naming style. setRadius, set_radius, SetRadius, SeTrADIUS, meTHOD234 are all valid. A common recommendation is to use Initial caps. However Main must be called Main

Comment: @pm100 Just because they "can" does not mean that they "should", which I think Bradley correctly describes.

Answer (score 0):

Well the C# is a case sensitive language. So the main needs to be in a Pascal case:

```
public static void Main(String[] args)
```